# Updating json inserting a \ with double quotes

Tags: powershell

I have a test.json file as follows

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings":  
         {"Default": "Server=1.2.3.4;User ID=meme;Password=youyou;Database=meyou;"    }
}
```

I like to change a few fields in this using power-shell. My code is as follows

```
$a = Get-Content 'G:\sandbox\test.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$a.ConnectionStrings = '"Default": "Server=5.6.7.8;User ID=hehe;Password=sheshe;Database=heshe;"'
$a | ConvertTo-Json  | set-content 'G:\sandbox\test.json'
```

The test.json becomes as follows.

```
"ConnectionStrings":  "\"Default\": \"Server=5.6.7.8;User ID=hehe;Password=sheshe;Database=heshe;\""
```

Basically all the double quotes got prefixed with a \ . How can I get rid of this extra \ from the output of the script ?

Comment: `$a.ConnectionStrings.Default="Server=5.6.7.8;User ID=hehe;Password=sheshe;Database=heshe;"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

```
$a.ConnectionStrings.Default="Server=5.6.7.8;User ID=hehe;Password=sheshe;Database=heshe;"
```

That is,

- instead of trying to assign a JSON-like fragment `'"Default": "Server=..."'` to the top-level `$a.ConnectionStrings` object in an attempt to update the nested `Default` object,
- assign the `"Server=..."` value to the `$a.ConnectionStrings.Default` property, relying on the fact that `ConvertFrom-Json` correctly mapped the input JSON to a nested custom object in PowerShell.

---

Your own attempt resulted in the nested object stored in `$a.ConnectionStrings` getting replaced with *string literal* (`"Default": "Server=..."`), whose *embedded* `"` chars. later needed `\`-escaping in the process of reconversion to JSON via `ConvertTo-Json`.